# datetime conversion from string in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime

when trying to convert string object into date…

here s is a string..

======datetime_new.py============

```
s="05/30/2013:10:47:34"

mytime = time.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

print mytime
```

getting an error like:

> ValueError: time data '05/30/2013:10:47:34' does not match format
>   '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 2):

There's a colon between date and time parts, but a space in your format.

But `time.strptime` won't give you a `datetime`, it will give you a `time.struct_time`. If you want a datetime, use `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: s="05/30/2013:10:47:34"

In [4]: mytime = time.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S")

In [5]: mytime
Out[5]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=10, tm_min=47, tm_sec=34, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=150, tm_isdst=-1)

In [6]: import datetime

In [7]: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 30, 10, 47, 34)
```